# wild card to find any character using like

Tags: mysql, sql, special-characters

Can anyone advice on is there away to use a special character search to find any character in the Notes Column

This is the query i'm running but unsure what to put in after like

COUNT(CASE WHEN notes like '' THEN 1 END) AS `stored`

The thing is notes can contain any character or numeric value, I want to search for those entires only as there's other rows that are just empty

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if there is at least one character, then you can simply do:

```
SUM( notes <> '' )
```

If you need to use `LIKE`, you can use the `_` wildcard:

```
SUM( notes LIKE '_%' )
```